# Microsoft Graph API userInfo endpoint UnknownError: Token must contain sub claim

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I'm trying to execute the userinfo endpoint at https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo using an access token received through Open ID Connect.

The response received is:

400 Bad Request

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "Token must contain sub claim.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-22T07:14:37",
            "request-id": "650a2928-b0e7-49ae-9e6d-ecb569ee69e6",
            "client-request-id": "650a2928-b0e7-49ae-9e6d-ecb569ee69e6"
        }
    }
}
```

The access token is valid and does contain a sub claim.

If I sign-in to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, and use the access token it automatically retrieves, it works - for the same user. The sub claim is different though and there are two of them.

It seems the token from OIDC doesn't have a correct sub claim - how come might this be?

Access token from directly from the /authorize endpoint [WORKING]:
[image: Access token from directly from the /authorize endpoint]

Access token from OIDC [NOT WORKING]:
[image: Access token from OIDC]

OIDC configuration:

```
options.Authority = authority;
options.ClientId = Configuration[ConfigKeys.IdentityProvider.ClientID];
options.ClientSecret = Configuration[ConfigKeys.IdentityProvider.ClientSecret];

options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
options.CallbackPath = Configuration[ConfigKeys.IdentityProvider.CallbackPath];
options.SignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

options.CorrelationCookie.Expiration
    = options.NonceCookie.Expiration
    = options.ProtocolValidator.NonceLifetime
    = options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout
    = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);

options.Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
options.SaveTokens = true;

options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("profile");
options.Scope.Add("email");
options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
options.Scope.Add("groups");

options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = authority,
    //NameClaimType = "name"
};
```

Comment: Did you parse the token to view it?

Comment: Yes - https://jwt.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The access token is valid and does contain a sub claim.

I suppose you didn't get the token correctly, please follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal)

2.In the `API permissions` of the AD App, add the following permission in Microsoft Graph

[image]

3.In the `Authentication`, choose the options below.

[image]

4.Hit the URL below in the browser, replace the `<tenant-id>`, `<client-id>` of yours, login your user account, then you will get an `access_token` and an `id_token`.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client-id>&response_type=token+id_token&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=user.read+openid+profile+email&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

5.Use the `access_token` to call the `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` endpoint, it works fine, the `sub` value is `EY4uO7uc1IG2n8EboEalB4LDxJ1NU8nuc2JXZgkisN4` in my sample.

[image]

6.Decode the `id_token` got in step 4 in https://jwt.io/, the `sub` is also `EY4uO7uc1IG2n8EboEalB4LDxJ1NU8nuc2JXZgkisN4`, so it means the `sub` got from `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` endpoint is correct.

[image]

> If I sign-in to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, and use the access token it automatically retrieves, it works - for the same user. The sub claim is different though and there are two of them.

The token you got from Microsoft Graph Explorer is an `access_token`, the first `sub` is the value for `access_token`, the second one is that you want i.e. `sub` of `id_token`.

[image]

> It seems the token from OIDC doesn't have a correct sub claim - how come might this be?

It is correct, as I mentioned above, the `sub` you got from the OIDC is the same as the `sub` got from the `id_token`.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#userinfo-response

> These are the same values that the app would see in the [ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) issued to the app.

**Note:** You may find the `sub` got manually is different from the second `sub` got from the MS Graph Explorer, this is because your user account logged in two different clients, one is the client of Graph Explorer, another one is your custom AD App.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

[image]

**Update:**

OIDC does not use the v2.0 endpoint, to solve this issue, we need to configure OIDC to make it use the v2.0 endpoint, just add `v2.0` in the `authority` of the configuration.

Comment: the information you provided is excellent however it's not working yet. I set the Graph API permissions which weren't there before, then got an access token from the /authorize endpoint using the tenantid and clientid parameters - this worked. Comparing with the access token from OIDC, it contains the same access_token 'sub' but not the id_token 'sub' - it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3167162 Could you elaborate on this `Comparing with the access token from OIDC, it contains the same access_token 'sub' but not the id_token 'sub'`? Maybe with some snapshots in https://jwt.io/? Did you get both the `access_token` and `id_token` from `/authorize` endpoint? Which token you used to call `/oidc/userinfo`?

Comment: I've retrieved two access tokens and tested them against the ```/oidc/userinfo``` endpoint: one directly from the ```/authorize``` endpoint, as you instructed - it works. A second through ```OIDC``` - which does not work. Please see additional info above.

Comment: @user3167162 Where did you get the code sample from? Could you provide a link?

Comment: It's from personal code which is part of a .Net Core application of ours - that sample includes the entire OIDC config but let me know if there's anything else you'd like to see.

Comment: @user3167162 Try `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;` in your code.

Comment: Although I can't say for sure, enabling ```GetUserClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint``` seems to encounter the same issue (400 Bad Request)

Comment: @user3167162 The config looks correct, not sure what causes this, what is your scenario, could you try to [use the MSAL to get the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)? repo - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet

Comment: The scenario requires us to retrieve user claims from the ```/userinfo endpoint``` (the ```id_token``` won't fit them). How this works: I authenticate through ```OIDC```, through a ```.Net Core challenge request```, and then make a direct call to the ```/userinfo``` endpoint with the ```access_token``` it returns.

Comment: I found OIDC calls the authorize endpoint without a 'v2.0' specification and if I add it then it works. https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/<v2.0>/authorize. Please let me know if you know how to configure OIDC to make it use the v2.0 url.

Comment: @user3167162 Add `v2.0` in the `authority`.

Comment: That's it, please add this to your answer, thanks.

Comment: @user3167162 Done.